# Python email (with txt and html)

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm trying to send and email with html and txt. But I need the contents of the .txt file into the email html body. And so far I can only get the txt file to work or the html, but not both. Any ideas?

```
import smtplib

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

sender = "sender@gmail.com"
receiver = "receiver@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "update"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

f1 = (open("email_data.txt"))
text = MIMEText(f1.read(),'plain') 

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  Header
  <body>
    <p>Something<br>
       Update<br>
       Need the contents of the text file to open here
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""


#part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(text)
msg.attach(part2)


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("sender", "password")
server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
print 'Email sent'
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great case for [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('username','password')

html = '<h1>some header text</h1><p>{}</p>'.format(f1.read())

yag.send('toaddr@gmail.com', 'subject', html)
```

Done.

Best to read the yagmail documentation at the link above to see what magic is actually happening.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Feel free to accept the answer or like on github :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for string formatting, the most basic use case is

```
"""the text i want to insert is the following {} """.format(text)
```

Comment: The text I want to insert is a big file that changes every time I run the script that has the email as the final output, so I'll always have different text in there.